# Laravel 5 - PayPal not getting Price when calling API

Tags: laravel, paypal, laravel-5

For some reason PayPal isn't receiving the total price I'm assigning to the transaction.

I'm using NetShell's PayPal module.

I have my controller that looks like this:

```
class PayPalController extends Controller {

    private $_apiContext;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
            config('services.paypal.client_id'),
            config('services.paypal.secret'));

        $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));
    }

    public function getCheckout() {
        $payer = PayPal::Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $amount = PayPal::Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD');
        $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,
        // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
        // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

        $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');

        $redirectUrls = PayPal::RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('PayPalController@getDone'));
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('PayPalController@getCancel'));

        $payment = PayPal::Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
        $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

        return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl );
    }

    // Other functions here. Removed for question.

}
```

`getCheckout()` gets called at the route `/paypal/checkout'

When I go to `/paypal/checkout` there is no price.

[image: This is what I see on PayPal. No price...]

Have I missed something? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be about the price type.Price must be declared in float.
Try,

```
floatval($price)
```

And check this out,I wrote about integrating paypal express to laravel,

[Paypal express integration](http://metekabak.com/php-paypal-express-integration)

Comment: You made $transaction->setAmount(floatval($amount)); right? Then try to use omnipay paypal package if you like to?

Comment: `Object of class PayPal\Api\Amount could not be converted to double`

Comment: Cause your amount is an object, seriously check this out, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ it has total paramater inside that object, use it.

Comment: I'm really new to this and don't really understand the the docs there. I'm doing what it says in terms of code but it still gives me that error.

Comment: try $transaction->setAmount($amount->total); or try $transaction->setAmount(floatval($amount->total));

Comment: If not, dd or return the $amount variable. paste to the question. I'm gonna try to help.

Comment: `Amount {#166 ▼
  -_propMap: array:2 [▼
    "currency" => "USD"
    "total" => "42"
  ]
}`

Comment: get the total and convert to float, that's your issue

Comment: So I'm now using this: `$transaction->setAmount(floatval($amount->total));` and it throws: `Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.`. This is confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: This became another issue now, try to use omnipay. it is a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. Is there a tutorial somewhere with how to use it with Laravel 5? Can't find one.

Comment: i wrote an example about it, used in blog https://gist.github.com/metekabak/1281bc0e2d80b33f5666

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81826/discussion-between-kriiv-and-mete-kabak).